# Not able to access CronJobDetail object when class is With sharing mode

Tags: sharing, with-sharing, without-sharing

I am not able to access CronJobDetail object when my class is in with sharing mode.
Getting the below error:

> sObject type 'CronJobDetail' is not supported.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your class is using Salesforce.com API version 29 or higher as noted in [CronJobDetail doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm)